# Cleanest safest way to modifying objects/external variables with GCD

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Apple recommends modifying an external variable by using static global or __block storage types.

dispatch_async() requires a block with no arguments.

What's the cleanest safest way to modify self.prop from within that block?

Use an atomic setter?

Wrap the block in a block?

Dispatch back to the main thread?

My scenario:
The block is making a network request.
When it's finished I have to parse some of the returned data and set the properties on a few different objects so that I can make follow up network requests.
The blocks are being processed async but depending on the user input the second block could be submitted to the queue with data needed from the first block. 
Here's what I'd like to do.

```
@implementation MyNetworkManager {
  dispatch_queue_t op_queue;
  NSURL *_redirectedURL;
}

void (^initPageOperation) (void) = ^(void) {
  NSURL *url;
  NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest;
  url = [NSURL URLWithString:domain];
  urlRequest =
  [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                      timeoutInterval:5];
  [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

  NSData *data = nil;
  NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
  NSError *err = nil;

  data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                               returningResponse:&urlResponse
                                           error:&err];

  if (urlResponse) {
     if (![urlResponse.URL isEqual:url]) {
            //Here's where I want to set the redirectedURL.
            _redirectedURL = urlResponse.URL;
     }
   }
};
```

Comment: It depends on the type of the property and how the property is used elsewhere.  Please make your question more specific.

Comment: There's no single answer to this question. It entirely depends on the specifics of the code and the multithreading/multiprocessing architecture you're working on. Can you add more specifics about your exact scenario?

Comment: @robmayoff I have a hypothetical scenario. In general I'm trying to understand best practices with blocks.

Comment: Watch the [“Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC” video from WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712).  Of particular interest is the section starting at about 36 minutes 20 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple recommendation is related to modifying the *contents of* a variable. If you are instead modifying an object *referenced by* a variable (`self.prop` in your case) then the question is the same with or without GCD - how do you write a property/method so that it is thread safe?

There are multiple answers to that (`@synchronized { }`, `dispatch_semaphore_X()`, `NSLock`, ...), research ensuring thread safety and find which meets your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> Apple recommends modifying an external variable by using static global or `__block` storage types.

I'm not sure I would have phrased it that way. I think a more logical way of thinking of it is "if you want to modify a method's local variable, you would use the `__block` qualifier on that variable's declaration, but otherwise that qualifier is not needed". In short, the `__block` qualifier is not needed for class instance variables (or properties), `static` variables, global variables, etc.

You go on to say:

> dispatch_async() requires a block with no arguments.

Sure, that's true. But then, again, if you're writing your own completion blocks, you can define them to have parameters. Or you might use an API call that has its own type of completion block with its own parameters. For example:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           // here you can initiate the parse of the data,
                           // capturing the url from the response, or examining
                           // the error
                       }];
```

That `completionHandler` is a block that takes parameters.

So, yes, a simple `dispatch_async` (or the `NSOperationQueue` equivalent, `addOperationWithBlock`) doesn't take parameters, as you start writing your own completion blocks, you'll often write ones that take parameters.

> What's the cleanest safest way to modify `self.prop` from within that block?

Technically, you can just modify it. The trick, though, is if you have multiple threads that might be accessing this simultaneously, then you'd synchronize your interaction with that class property through one of the [locking mechanisms](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) or you can [eliminate that locking code by performing all interaction with that class property with a serial queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW3) (either a serial queue you create or the main queue).

> Use an atomic setter?

That only works with [simple data types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW2). When dealing with objects, though, the atomic setter doesn't buy you much. You need some other mechanism for synchronizing interaction with your variable, such as those described above.

> Wrap the block in a block?

Sort of, but it's not technically the wrapping it in a block that provides thread safety, it's the dispatching of that block to a serial queue (and ensuring that all other interaction with that property is done on the same serial queue).

> Dispatch back to the main thread?

In certain simple cases, yes, that can do the job, too. But make sure you're not dispatching anything terribly time consuming to the main thread or else your UI may be affected (or worse).

> I have a hypothetical scenario. In general I'm trying to understand best practices with blocks.

There are so many different patterns, a hypothetical question is hard to answer, because the details differ entirely depending upon precisely what the business needs are. For best practices, I'd encourage you to watch the WWDC video Rob Mayoff referenced, [Asynchronous Design Patterns with Blocks, GCD, and XPC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=712). You can also see WWDC 2012 [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211). Those build on concepts on earlier videos, too, such as WWDC 2011 videos such as [Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch in Practice](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=308) and [Mastering Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=210).